# how to store the class objects in function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to store the class objects data in function. But i am unable to add the class objects into function. how can i store the class objects into function.

Below is my Snippet.

```
class Dict:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        if data is None:
            data = {}
        self.data = data

    def create(self, k, v):
        self.data[k] = v
        print(self.data[k])


    def data(args):
        pass

d = Dict(data)

for i in range(2):
   k = input('Enter a key :')
   v = int(input('Enter a value :'))
   d.create(k,v)
```

Comment: ` i am unable to add` Why ? Do you have errors ? Please explain what is not working; What is the `data` you try to apss in the constructor ?

Comment: What do you mean "store the class objects data in function" ??? Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `data` of you class expects a value or nothing, if you want to passe something, it has to be defined

- pass nothing, a empty dict will be used in the class

  ```
  d = Dict()
  ```
- pass a non-empty dict to your class

  ```
  values = {'k1' : 123, 'k2: 456}
  d = Dict(values)
  ```